# VS2013 Adding Types to Code Map forces Rebuilding Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-map

We have a large solution (112 projects) in VS2013 Ultimate.

I love the [Code Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835(v=vs.120).aspx) feature, however when I am dragging types onto a Code Map dgml it insists on building the solution - even though I have not made any changes.

I can't see many options for this great feature, but is there anyway to tell it to stop building the solution everytime I add a type to the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and major complaint with Code Map in Visual Studio 2013. It affects certain types of projects (like ASP.NET ones) more than others because these projects always report that they have changes and need to be rebuilt.

The experience is improved in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, as we have added a "skip build" option.

[image]

We've made many improvements to CodeMap in Visual Studio 2015, so it's definitely worth getting it if you use Code Maps. Note that you can install VS 2015 along side VS 2013, so you don't have to migrate projects etc.

Comment: Thanks for that info Bogdan.  I already have VS2015 installed alongside VS2013.  All the team use VS2013 having recently upgraded from VS2010.  I have put off using VS2015 with our product for that reason.  From what I tried a while ago when opening a project clone in VS2015 made changes to either solution or project files but it would not prevent it from opening in either version.

Comment: Its when I load the solution in VS2015 I get the upgrade message "Visual Studio has made non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior." which scares me.  Oddly enough, every time I open the solution I get the same upgrade message and a new backup folder appears.  This is crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I see the code map document window in VS 2015 now contains a button labelled "Skip Build" which seems to solve this problem